# Swap memory on SSDs

Tags: memory, ssd, swap

Swap memory isn't very worth it in a HDD because of the low writing speed.

However with the increasing popularity of SSD, and their faster writing/reading speeds, **Does having a swap memory on a SSD is worth it and how much storage should be this swap partition?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, worth it.

I already work with a desktop PC in my last job with a limited amount of memory RAM and HDD. Sometimes, I run out of memory RAM and my Linux starts to swapping, what is a nightmare that we already know.

So, my company upgraded my machine with a SSD. I can say to you that the swapping in SSD is very, very fast. You can work without some problems with the SO using swap memory in a SSD without even knowing that this is happening.

The amount of swap space depends of your use. For instance, you can use this table as reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/49138/467504

```
Amount of RAM in the system   Recommended swap space         Recommended swap space 
                                                             if allowing for hibernation
---------------------------   ----------------------------   ---------------------------
2GB of RAM or less            2 times the amount of RAM      3 times the amount of RAM
2GB to 8GB of RAM             Equal to the amount of RAM     2 times the amount of RAM
8GB to 64GB of RAM            0.5 times the amount of RAM    1.5 times the amount of RAM
64GB of RAM or more           4GB of swap space              No extra space needed
```

Comment: I don't think that last line in the table is correct.

Comment: That table does not make sense, 60GB of ram need 30/90gb whereas 64 gb needs 4/0?

Comment: @eckes I don't understand what you mean. The table are saying that if you have 64GB de ram you need few swap space (only 4GB). But this is only a reference.

Comment: You can't hibernate that way @Dherik